# How to target specific handlers with a @ControllerAdvice @ModelAttribute?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-4

I'd like to display a warning message on specific pages 5 minutes prior to a system shutdown. Rather than add it manually to each these pages I created a @ControllerAdvice class with a @ModelAttribute method that adds the message to the Model parameter, but from what I understand reading the documentation and SO and some initial testing this model attribute will be added to every method with a @RequestMapping.

I realize I could refactor my code so that the targeted methods are all in one controller and limit the @ControllerAdvice to that one controller, but I would end up with a collection of otherwise non-related methods in that controller which muddies up the overall structure of my controllers.

So, is there a way to indicate which specific methods in multiple controllers the @ModelAttribute is applied to? Would a custom annotation be a solution (not sure how that would work)? I'd like to do this via annotations if possible.

**Edit:**

The @ControllerAdvice code is pretty basic:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalModelController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private MaintenanceInterceptor maintInterceptor; 

    @ModelAttribute()
    public void globalAttributes(Model model, Locale locale) {
        if (maintInterceptor.isMaintenanceWindowSet() && !maintInterceptor.isMaintenanceInEffect()) {
            String msg = maintInterceptor.getImminentMaint(locale);
            model.addAttribute("warningMaint", msg);
            logger.debug("maint msg= " + msg);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code to clarify what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A controller advice can be limited to certain controllers (not methods) by using one of the values of the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation, e.g.

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {MyController1.class, MyController2.class})
```

If you need to do it on a method level I suggest to take a look at [Interceptors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor).

Comment: I'm actually using an interceptor to redirect to a "System Unavailable" page once maintenance has started.  So, your suggestion would be to look at the handler parameter in the preHandle method and add the message to the request as a session attribute, not a model attribute?

Comment: The interceptor has access to the model in the `postHandle` method. _"add to the request as a session attribute"_ is a contradiction. You would simply add it to the request.

Comment: My bad, I should have looked at the `postHandle` method before commenting.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @zeroflagL for pointing me to the interceptor solution. I ditched the `@ControllerAdvice` approach and ended up with this:

**Custom annotation:**

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface MaintAware {
    String name() default "MaintAware";
}
```

**Interceptor:**

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod)handler;
    Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
    MaintAware maintAware = method.getAnnotation(MaintAware.class);
    if (maintAware != null) {
        Locale locale = request.getLocale();
        if (isMaintenanceWindowSet() && !isMaintenanceInEffect()) {
            String msg = getImminentMaint(locale);
            if (!msg.isEmpty())
                modelAndView.addObject("warningMaint", msg);
        }
    }

    super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
}
```

Now I can annotate the specific methods that require the maintenance notification.  Easy peasy. :)