# @ControllerAdvice being called for all Controllers, not just basePackageClasses

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I cannot provide the actual code since it is on another system but the issue I am seeing in my Spring 4.2.6 Web Release is the use of basePackageClasses not actually mapping to the controller.

Let's say I have 3 Controllers:  AController.class, BController.class, and CController.class.

For each I have created a ControllerAdvice: AControllerAdvice.class,BControllerAdvice.class & CControllerAdvice.class.

I use the annotation as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = AController.class)
public class AControllerAdvice{
  @ModelAttribute
  public void addModelInformation(Model model){
    //controller specific model information for header and footer added here
  }
}
```

What I am experiencing is that when I call a rest method in AController.class, I have verified that via logging, that the 'addModelInformation' method is being called from all three ControllerAdvice's and thus the last one called by Spring's ordering sets the header and footer with the net effect that the header and footer remain static.

Via documentation Spring should support and my understanding is that only the ControllerAdvice for the rest method residing within that mapped controller should be called.  So I have to conclude that I have set up something wrong.  I am using JavaConfig and look forward to hearing from you guys!

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36042624/8232755

Comment: Thank you Thoomas for your response!  Currently, when the other did not work, I went the Interceptor route to handle the need for unique header/footer model information.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `assignableTypes`:

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = AController.class)
public class AControllerAdvice {
    @ModelAttribute
    public void addModelInformation(Model model){
         //controller specific model information for header and footer added here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Nikolay!  I am not certain how I overlooked 'assignableTypes' but by your example it appears that is exactly what I am looking for!!  I will try this a bit later this morning!

Comment: I wanted to follow up and affirm your answer, I created a 'global' advice to add view items common to all pages and then a specific one  for a specific page and only saw the value added when that controller was called.  Thank you again so very much for your time and effort in answering my question!

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the config classes to `@ControllerAdvice`'s basePackageClasses not controller classes.

Assume you have Configuration named with `ConfigClass`

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass {
    @Bean
    public AController controllerA() {
        ....
    }
    ... // your controllers to be weaved
}
```

Then you should setup advice with

`@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = ConfigClass.class)`

Comment: Thank you SungJin Steve Yoo!  I did not realize that the configuration classes are applicable to the 'basePackageClasses', currently I have one config class for all of the controllers, so if I am understanding your solution, I would have to create a config for each controller that I wanted handled separately by ControllerAdvice?  Am I understanding your suggestion correctly?  i.e., in the example I provided then I would have a AConfigClass.class, BConfigClass.class, and CConfigClass.class and specify those to the corresponding ControllerAdvice.

Comment: @JavaJd Unlikely to above vote upped  answers, if you want your bunch of controllers managed equally then you should do like me.

Comment: `basePackageClasses` will cause `@ControllerAdvice` to advise controller types that are defined in those packages. I don't think it's likely that the `ConfigClass` is in the same package as the controllers.

Comment: @Sotirios oh my! you are right. I assumed like it is in the same package structure.