# How to hide the response from ExceptionHandlers for specific endpoints in Springdoc OpenAPI

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, springdoc

There is a Spring Boot application where exceptions are handled within a general `@ControllerAdvice` and several `@ExceptionHandler`. For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) // 403
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedCustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccessDeniedException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ...
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) // 404
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundCustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFoundException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And with this configuration I get generated OpenAPI yaml file with the responses 403 and 404 for every endpoint.

I want to hide 403 for some specific endpoints, how can I do that?

I know about `@Hidden` annotation for handler method, but it removes response code from every endpoint. It isn't a desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding some responses from several endpoints can be done by using parameters in `@ControllerAdvice` annotation. You can split your handler methods by groups with the same behavior in different ControllerAdvice classes.

Then for one `@ControllerAdvice` annotation you can specify applied condition by `basePackages` or `assignableTypes`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36042624/3465146 answer for details.

But this solution isn't ideal if you have a lot of endpoints with common behavior and only a few exceptional endpoints with less responses. It would be great if there was a simple solution for this specific case, but I couldn't find it.